# highchart get each drilldown categories name on click event

Tags: javascript, events, highcharts, onclick

For HighChart below is my data:

```
data = [

    { y:11,color: colors[7],
            drilldown:{  name:'X',categories: [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ],
            data: [ 73, 5, 2, 3 ],
            color: colors[5] 
            } 
    }, 
    { y:7,color: colors[7],
            drilldown:{  name:'Y',categories: [ 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' ],
            data: [ 16, 2, 3, 20  ],color: colors[5] 
            } 
    }, 

    so on
    .
    .
    ];
```

it works on click event I check for 'drilldown' and I can get the 'name'.
but, in the 2nd level of drilldonw I can not seem to get the categories name on click event.

```
        events: {
              click: function() {

                 var drilldown = this.drilldown;
                 //var drilldownC = this.drilldown.categories;

                 if (drilldown) { // drill down

                      setChartC(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, drilldown.data, drilldown.color, drilldown.level);

                 } else { // restore
                    setChartC(name, categories, data, null, level);
                    alert(this.options.name);
                 }

              }
           }
```

How can I get the 'categories: [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]' name on click event?
Please help!

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by restructuring the data structure and giving a "Name" for each categories.